# jquery kendo-ui add attribute and class to checkbox tree item

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Where I am appending my dynamic checkbox items within a loop, I tried adding the additional suffix as seen below:

```
checkBoxTree.append({ text: plc + " (" + id + ")"}).attr("data-id", id).className = "id-item class";
```

I get no errors, but the attribute and two classes are not added anywhere. How Is this done?

*the attempted above adding this at the end of where I'm writing the new checkbox elems'*`.attr("data-id", id).className = "id-item class`*";'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not play with Kendo's DOM, it's constantly redrawn. I suggest using [`template`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/configuration/template) and wrapping the item content's inside a `div`. Then add any class or data attribute you would need over that `div`, instead of the item's `li`. Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
let tv = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  template: "<div data-id='#= item.id #' class='id-item class'>#= item.text # (#= item.inStock #)</div>",
  dataSource: [
    { text: "foo", inStock: 7, items: [
      { text: "bar", inStock: 2 },
      { text: "baz", inStock: 5 }
    ] }
  ]
}).data('kendoTreeView');
  
tv.append({ text: 'abc', id: 10, inStock: 1000 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/EKiyidIQ)

If you inspect above tree's *abc* node, you will see...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so I really can't add selectors onto the checkboxe items themselves? that seems a little crazy

Comment: @docholiday you can but they are lost real easily. I mean, try adding a class manually to a tree node or grid row for example, then hit any function like refresh, transport read.. all changes to DOM will be lost because that content is unconditionally redrawn.

Comment: I understand what you mean, was hoping their API would have a way to handle that, seems absurd to not be able to add and access raw dom elements. Thanks for the above, perhaps I can get it with some psuedo selectors

Comment: @docholiday try using `data-uid`.